# C# Convert IntPtr to object Instance, instead of object copy

Tags: c#, c++

I'm working on a project that uses both C++ and C#.
However, when passing C#, i get a copy instead of the actual object, which doesn't work for me because i need to read and write to it both on on C# and C++.

on C++ the class looks like this:

```
class TestClass {
    public:
        float f1;
        float f2;
}
```

whereas on C# the class looks like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 0x8)]
public class TestClass {
    [FieldOffset(0x0)] public float f1;
    [FieldOffset(0x4)] public float f2;
}
```

then the way i read it in C# is by doing this:

```
    public class TestProgram {
        public static CTestClass Test;
        public static delegate void SetTestDelegate(IntPtr pTest);
        public static void SetTest(IntPtr pTest) {
            if (pTest == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            object? TestObj = Marshall.PtrToStrucutre(pTest, typeof(TestClass))
            if (TestObj == null)
                return;

            Test = (TestClass)TestObj;
        }
    }
```

the SetTest method gets invoked on C++ like this:

```
typedef void (*tSetTest) (TestClass* pClass):

void SetNetTest() {
    // code that gets the library path and stuff here
        
    tSetTest SetTest;
    hostfxr_load_assembly(wsLibPath.c_str(), L"TestProgram, testlib", L"SetTest", L"TestProgram+SetTestDelegate, testlib", nullptr, (void**)&SetTest);
    
    TestClass* pTestClass = new TestClass();
    SetTest(pTestClass);
}
```

but this just returns a copy of the object at the time of reading it rather than an actual instance of it.

is there any way i can change that without using unsafe code or writing setters/getters in C++?

Comment: Try using a `struct` instead of a `class`

Comment: thanks for the advice,
i tried that but unfortunately, it still acts as a copy of the struct

Comment: Why not `void SetTest(TestClass test)`? Do you import some functions from C++? If so, please show their declarations.

Comment: You made the copy by calling Marshal.PtrToStructure().  That's a good way to read the unmanaged object.  Maybe you meant to store the IntPtr so you can later call Marshal.StructureToPtr(), but that is rather a wild guess.

Comment: SetTest gets invoked on C++, via hostfxr, i'll add that to the original question though, thanks, as for storing the IntPtr and reading it every time, it's a good idea, but for what i'm doing, i dunno if it'd work because i need to read and write a ton of times per second, Marshal.PtrToStrucutre may affect performance a ton